# Can I use an sqlite database on OneDrive (in the cloud) like a local database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, onedrive

Actaully, I have an application that use an Sql Lite database in local. But I would like that all the users could use the same data base instead of each one has its own database.

So I am thinking in the possiblity to upldoad a database to the cloud, for example to OneDrive, and access to that like it would be a local database.

When I mean that like a local database, I mean that I want to avoid to download the data base, make changes and later upload the database again, because this is not a good option for concurrency access.

I would like that if I do an update, only change the data that I want to update, because also I want to avoid to download all the database and save data if I connect with a mobile connection.

I sumary, the only change that I would like to do to my application is add support to use the API needed to access to files stored in OneDrive and change the path of the database from my local database to the database stored in OneDrive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can map the OneDrive cloud disk as Network unit in Windows I think it is possible to work on it directly from an application just passing the correct path on the network drive ...

I can't say if the performance achieved will be acceptable for you, but is definitely possible to work on it through a network drive . Take a look at [this](http://thetechl33t.com/2014/03/14/how-to-mount-your-onedrive-as-a-local-mapped-drive/) blog post that will show you how to map OneDrive space as network drive .

Comment: Thanks so much. After maping the folder, I can use the application just setting the path of the database in my confing file. The problem is that is slower than if I use a database stored in a remote desktop which has a bandwidth of 6Mb/1Mb (down/up). I thought that using OneDrive i would get better performace in this, but it seems that if the response is slow is not for the bandwith. In local work perfectly.